# Change image in Word Shape via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have word document with InlineShape in it. I want programmatically via VBA change image in this shape. But all examples which I found replaced old shape for new. And all formatting (size, borders and so on) are lost.  How change only image in shape without losing formatting in it.

```
Dim pic = _m.off.wd.doc.Range(Start:=startRange).InlineShapes(1)
Dim picRange = pic.Range
Dim cImgPath = getPhotoPathFromRow(cR, cTyp)
Dim newPic = _m.off.wd.doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(cImgPath, False, True, picRange)
pic.Delete()
```

But not copy formatting from old picture. How make code to copy all format settings from old (deleted) picture?

Comment: Your question is not very clear... is there an image in a shape - what kind of shape is it, something like a text-box?

Comment: I thank for your attention and I’m sorry for my poor English. My task is this. In Word-document among text blocks placed one picture. Above code (I add now) replace this picture by another without saving formatting. And I need replace only image and save formatting from old picture.

Comment: Question: If you manually paste the new picture into the document can you apply the formatting from from the old picture to the new picture using the format painter BEFORE deleting the old picture? If so, the same should be possible programmatically.

Comment: I have also tried idea to aplly copy formats. But in this case not all format settings  apply to new image. For example size of picture and text wrapping...  Is possible easy changing the image in shape like in html tag <IMG> or in winform controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to wrap your image in a Content Control - save size details, delete and replace with the new image, then reapply the size details.

```
Sub replaceImage()

    Dim originalImage As InlineShape
    Dim newImage As InlineShape

    Set originalImage = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)

    Dim imageControl As ContentControl

    If originalImage.Range.ParentContentControl Is Nothing Then
        Set imageControl = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlPicture, originalImage.Range)
    Else
        Set imageControl = originalImage.Range.ParentContentControl
    End If

    Dim imageW As Long
    Dim imageH As Long
    imageW = originalImage.Width
    imageH = originalImage.Height

    originalImage.Delete

    Dim imagePath As String
    imagePath = "C:\Users\SlowLearner\Pictures\Temp\testImage.jpg"
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture imagePath, False, True, imageControl.Range

    With imageControl.Range.InlineShapes(1)
        .Height = imageH
        .Width = imageW
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! You make great help for me!